# Why c++ has iostream when it has istream and stream?

Tags: c++, stream, stringstream

According to my test in vs2019, `ostream` takes 72 bytes, `istream` takes 80 bytes and `iostream` takes 88 bytes. There is no discernible difference in their size, so I don't think 'it's aimed at saving resource' is right.

Another confusing problem is why `istringstream` enables construction with `std::ios::out`?

Comment: How else do you propose implementing a stream that supports both input and output?

Comment: Basically to prevent simple errors like `std::cout >> x` and `std::cin << y`. Same reason you limit the interface on any class when you can, to avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The [openmode](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) for a stream is a [bitmask type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BitmaskType). I.e. it's a set of bits that you can use bitwise OR to add into a more complex set of flags.

The openmode flags for the string-streams are passed on to the underlying [string buffer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf) which is bidirectional.

Passing the flag `std::ios::out` when creating or opening an input-only stream is just silently ignored.

---

And the size of an object or a class is in almost all cases irrelevant, and comparing the sizes of unrelated objects (even in the same inheritance hierarchy) often have no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to read and write to the standard input/output streams, and it is also a standard.

Why would you `#include <istream>` and `#include <ostream>`. It makes sense to just `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: I _think_ the question talks about `sizeof(std::istream)`, not `<istream>`

Comment: Oh, fair point.